# "taskdef class .....FindBugsTask cannot be found" warning by Eclipse in build.xml file

Tags: eclipse, ant, findbugs, build.xml

As part of my project's build.xml file, we have the following block:

```
<taskdef name="findbugs" classpath="${findbugs.home}/lib/findbugs-ant.jar"
     classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask"/>
```

Recently, Eclipse IDE has started giving a warning on this line. The warning is "taskdef class edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask cannot be found".

I run ant findbugs from Cygwin command line, and with the code as is, it works great. I am just looking to resolve the Eclipse warning.

I'm sure not what caused this to start happening, but if I remove it and try to run `ant findbugs` I get a BUILD FAILED error `failed to create task or type findbugs`, which would obviously happen because I removed the taskdef.

How do I point `ant` to `findbugs` in a way that `FindBugsTask` is recognized?

So far, I have tried adding a path to the ant-findbugs.jar file to  Ant Home Entries in the Preferences tab, Ant > Runtime window in Eclipse, but that has had no effect.

Comment: My guess would be that Eclipse is attempting to evaluate the script before actually running it, so your `${findbugs.home}` property doesn't have a value yet and thus the classpath doesn't point to a jar file. Not a permanent solution, but you could try hard-coding that path to see if it makes the warning message disappear.

Comment: I have the lines

`<property name="findbugs.home" value="${toolsdir}/findbugs-3.0.1" />` and `<property name="toolsdir" value="${basedir}/tools" />`
 
early in the build.xml file, so I believe the properties are getting set correctly. I tried a hard coded path, but it doesn't seem to change anything and the warning still appears.